# spring-data compile errors in generated-sources

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation, spring-data

I checked out spring-data-commons, ran test in command line and it's ok.
My issue is when I imported into IntelliJ IDEA and run it in the IDE I'm getting compile errors in my :

> spring-data-commons\target\generated-sources\test-annotations

Any idea?

Comment: How exactly did you import the project in IntelliJ IDEA? From which file? Do you use Maven? What errors do you get? Please edit the question and provide the precise instructions to reproduce the problem and list the errors you are getting.

Comment: Try `mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` in the command line first. Does it build without errors? Does it build in IDEA then?

Answer (score 1):

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Is ok

In my opinion it's just an intellij missing config